# Extbase Query: Tricky access on parent

Tags: php, sql, typo3, extbase

I'm writing a very big extbase extension and have to handle some complicated filter functions. It would be a one liner in pure sql, however, I have to use Extbase ORM for various reasons.

This is about performances of theater plays. Every play has multiple performances, the play is the aggregate root.

I have to find performances within a given time range and that's a no-brainer. However, the category is a child of the parent (play). I do not save a reference of the play in the performance, but in the play (that's because the TCA has to be configured as select-type).

I have to forward the result to the paginator widget, which requires an instance of the QueryResultInterface. When I use the plays as aggregate root and extract the performances from there, it returns ObjectStorage and breaks the widget.

Is it somehow possible to restrict the output if a child of a parent category matches or am I assume right: there's no reasonable chance?

```
public function findByTimeRangeInBeginTimeAndAttendCategoryAndStartOfBooking(Datetime $startRange, Datetime $endRange, $category = 'undefined') {

        $query = $this->createQuery();

        $constraints = array();
        $constraints[] = $query->greaterThanOrEqual('timebegin', $startRange->getTimestamp());
        $constraints[] = $query->lessThanOrEqual('timebegin', $endRange->getTimestamp());

        if($category !== 'undefined') {
            $constraints[] = $query->equals('play.category.name', $category);
        }

        $query->matching (
            $query->logicalAnd($constraints)
        );
        $query->setOrderings (
                        Array('timebegin' => Tx_Extbase_Persistence_Query::ORDER_ASCENDING)
        );

        return $query->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is much chance without a reference to the play. I would even say your domain model cannot work out this way. Either you have play as aggregate root and then select the plays and go from there to the performances or the performance has a repository too and in that sense becomes an aggregate root itself, but then you would want to have a reference to the play...

Comment: The problem is, that I have to forward the result to the paginator widget, which requires an instance of the QueryResultInterface. When I use the plays as aggregate root and extract the plays from there, it returns ObjectStorage and breaks the widget ...

Answer (score 0):

> I have to use Extbase ORM for various reasons.
>   What reasons? Are you sure you really have to?

It won't solve your problem, but you should read this:
http://lists.typo3.org/pipermail/typo3-dev/2011-May/043180.html

I really like the idea to bring MVC and ORM to TYPO3 and I am using Extbase myself, but I'd go with a "regular" TYPO3-Extension or another framework if I had to write **complex** database-driven stuff.

Comment: I'm aware of that problems and I have times in my current project where I am really afraid if sticking to extbase was the right decision. I ended up with altering the domain model (as mentioned in your link). And I'm at a level now, when thinks start to slow down.